# Windows Server 2008 Best PHP/MySQL Combo

Tags: windows-server-2008, mysql, php

I'll soon be hosting a web server on windows server 2000, I need php and mysql, and i'm wondering which server is the best to work with these tools? Apache, Nginx, IIS with php?

Comment: Are you sure your mean Windows Server *2000*? Windows Server 2000 *extended* support [ended on 2010-07-13](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?LN=en-us&x=9&y=14&p1=7274).  Hosting anything Internet-facing on the Server 2000 platform may not be in your best interest

Comment: Windows 2000? Why do you want to use a 12 year old product that is out of maintenance and doesn't receive any security updates anymore?

Comment: Actually I misread :D its 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None. It's end of support and all of those applications and Linux native. Run them on their native platform on a current and supported OS.

Edit:

Since you've changed your question from server 2000 to 2008, I'd recommend using IIS unless you have a specific reason not to. It's the native server for the platform.

Answer (score 0):

to be honest its better to use linux for hosting php/mysql, Windows better for ASP/IIS 
but anyway from that 3 web servers use IIS.